# Undefined getTextContent() for SOAPElement java 8

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-8, javax.xml

Did anyone encounter this issue ?

I was using **javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement**'s getTextContent() with Java 7. But when I use Java 8 it gives me compilation error "**The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type SOAPElement**".

When I browsed through javadoc for java 8, I see that this method exists. Could anyone help me understand what's the problem here ?

Comment: How do you compile? Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Yes I am using eclipse IDE

Comment: Which version? Luna?

Comment: `SOAPElement s = null; s.getTextContent();` compiles fine with javac. If that simple 2 line code does not compile for you it may be an eclipse issue or a project configuration issue, in which case you need to give more information.

Comment: OK I will try to dig more into it ... And give you more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this problem in Eclipse, my tested solution would be: Java Build Path → Order and Export, select JRE System Library and move it to Top